# Seting culture info from the project properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating winforms app in Visual Studio 2019 in C# (.NET) and I have this code:

```
   CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de");
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

to set the culture info. However, I wonder if I can set culture info some other way manually like project -> properties but I cannot find it at the moment.

Is this possible?

Comment: From .config file key?

Comment: Really is this possible. That would do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<configuration>
  [...]
  <appSettings>
    [...]
    <add key="defaultCulture" value="de" />
    [...]
  </appSettings>
  [...]
</configuration>
```

and recover the value like this:

```
var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultCulture"];
```